# Поворот отрезка в пространстве

Tags: геометрия, 3d

На вход приходит какой-то случайны отрезок в пространстве в виде координат двух его концов p1(x1,y1,z1) и p2(x2,y2,z2).

Задача заключается в следующем - необходимо выполнить такие преобразования его координат, чтобы он был строго вертикален, при чем сохранив свою длину. Демонстрация на картинке (зеленый - исходный, синий - повернутый).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. была идея взять любую точку на исходном отрезке (обозначим A1), и достроить вторую точку (A2) которая выше точки А1 на длину исходного отрезка. Но так не пойдет, потому что преобразования которые мы применяем к отрезку чтобы его повернуть, будут применены и к другим 3D объектам.
2. также была идея вычислить угол между отрезком и всеми осями (x,y,z), и последовательно домножить все координаты отрезка на матрицу поворота по всем осям. Но новый отрезок после выполнения этой операции не удовлетворил ожиданиям (смотрел не строго вверх).

Здесь последовательно домножаю координаты на вот эти 3 матрицы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

угол альфа,бета,гамма заранее известен 45 градусов, можете проверить что угол взят верно, на картинке (зеленый отрезок) для примера взят отрезок с координатами p1(0,0,0) p2(1,1,1)

попытка реализации алгоритм  для получение матрицы поворота:

```
import numpy as np

# нормализовать вектор (привести к единичной длине)
def normalize_vector(vector):
    norm_v = np.linalg.norm(vector)
    if norm_v != 0:
        return vector / norm_v
    else:
        return vector

# Исходные данные задачи (2 конца отрезка)
x = np.array([0,0,0])
y = np.array([1,1,1])

#нормализуем вектора
x = normalize_vector(x)
y = normalize_vector(y)

# необходимые вектора для решения задачи
s = np.array([y[0] - x[0],y[1] - x[1],y[2] - x[2]])
t = np.array([0,1,0])
a = np.cross(s,t)

#нормализуем вектора
s = normalize_vector(s)
t = normalize_vector(t)
a = normalize_vector(a)

# матрицы
S = np.array([s, a, np.cross(s,a)])
T = np.array([t, a, np.cross(t,a)])

#транспонированная S
S_t = np.transpose(S)

# получаем решение задачи
solution = np.dot(S_t, T)

# тестируем, пробуем получить повернутый отрезок
x = np.array([[0,0,0]])
y = np.array([[1,1,1]])
x = np.dot(x, solution)
y = np.dot(y, solution)
x = np.round(x, decimals=2)
y = np.round(y, decimals=2)

print(x, y)
```

Comment: в первом пункте объяснил что необходимо повернуть с помощью преобразований (без создания новых объектов), так как вместе с отрезком будут поворачиваться и другие 3D объекты которые нельзя повернуть таким методом

Comment: если надо все повернуть - потребуется матрица поворота. Если результат не удовлетворил - скорее всего неверно рассчитал значения в матрице

Comment: Добавьте как считаете 2 вариант, может найдется ошибка

Comment: добавил метод вычисления в вопрос

Comment: У вас вектора столбцы или строки?

Comment: Сколько людей погибло комбинируя эйлеровы углы - не сосчитаешь. "Without considering the possibility of using two different conventions for the definition of the rotation axes (intrinsic or extrinsic), there exist twelve possible sequences of rotation axes..."

Comment: «необходимо выполнить такие преобразования его координат, чтобы он был строго вертикален, при чем сохранив свою длину»  — а какие ещё требования? А то ж можно просто построить отрезок из (0,0,0) нужной длины

Comment: @AlexeyTen, надо предъявить любое движение переводящее оригинальный отрезок в вертикальный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все вектора далее приводятся к единичной длине. Это важно.

Введём вектор *s = (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>2</sub> - z<sub>1</sub>)*.

Вектор *t = (0, 1, 0)*. Вектор *a = s × t* - векторное произведение (это будет ось поворота).

Из векторов соберем две матрицы:  *S = (s, a, s × a)* и *T = (t, a, t × a)*. "Соберем" означает что первый вектор становится первым столбцом матрицы, второй - вторым, третий - третьим.

Нужная вам матрица поворота есть *S<sup>-1</sup>·T*.

**P.S.** Алгебра выписана в предположении что вектора — вектора-строки, то есть умножение вектора на матрицу вычисляется как *v·M*. Если вектора — вектора-столбцы, то "сборка" матрицы меняется со столбцов на строки и последнее произведением имеет вид: *T·S<sup>-1</sup>*.

**P.P.S.** Если длина вектора *a* до нормализации близка к нулю, вектор *s* уже почти вертикальный. Можно не нормализовать, сразу вернуть единичную матрицу.

**P.P.P.S.** Общий метод решения подобных задач: для исходного и для конечного положений придумать два ортонормальных базиса. Из базисов составить две матрицы. Первую обратить и умножить на вторую - получится матрица перехода между базисами, что вам и нужно.

**P.P.P.P.S.** Задача может решена множеством способов, это решение - кратчайший поворот.

**P.P.P.P.P.S.** Демонстрация:

```py
import numpy as np


def normalized(v):
    return v / np.linalg.norm(v)


def get_rotation(x, y):
    s = normalized(y - x)
    t = np.array([0, 1, 0])

    a = np.cross(s, t)
    an = np.linalg.norm(a)
    if an == 0:
        return np.identity(3)
    a /= an

    sm = np.array([s, a, np.cross(s, a)])
    tm = np.array([t, a, np.cross(t, a)])
    return np.dot(np.transpose(sm), tm)


def test(x, y):
    print()
    print('x', x)
    print('y', y)

    r = get_rotation(x, y)
    
    # чистый поворот, но он смещает x
    # xm = np.dot(x, r)
    # ym = np.dot(y, r)

    # поворот вокруг x, x остаётся на месте
    xm = x
    ym = x + np.dot(y - x, r)

    print('xm', xm)
    print('ym', ym)
    print('ym - xm', ym - xm)
    print('norm(y - x)', np.linalg.norm(y - x))


test(np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 1, 1]))
for _ in range(5):
    test(np.random.random(3), np.random.random(3))
```

> ```
> $ python motion.py
>
> x [0 0 0]
> y [1 1 1]
> xm [0 0 0]
> ym [8.32667268e-17 1.73205081e+00 1.11022302e-16]
> ym - xm [8.32667268e-17 1.73205081e+00 1.11022302e-16]
> norm(y - x) 1.7320508075688772
>
> x [0.09054937 0.25113354 0.84059327]
> y [0.66784923 0.45813704 0.97364723]
> xm [0.09054937 0.25113354 0.84059327]
> ym [0.09054937 0.87869146 0.84059327]
> ym - xm [-1.38777878e-17  6.27557916e-01  0.00000000e+00]
> norm(y - x) 0.627557915509163
>
> x [0.45851044 0.61577351 0.9463866 ]
> y [0.79713568 0.81397556 0.91020798]
> xm [0.45851044 0.61577351 0.9463866 ]
> ym [0.45851044 1.00980396 0.9463866 ]
> ym - xm [0.         0.39403046 0.        ]
> norm(y - x) 0.3940304551397485
>
> x [0.19882745 0.59956245 0.47065679]
> y [0.94670724 0.47282411 0.67784346]
> xm [0.19882745 0.59956245 0.47065679]
> ym [0.19882745 1.38589132 0.47065679]
> ym - xm [0.         0.78632888 0.        ]
> norm(y - x) 0.7863288771527435
>
> x [0.70422901 0.08023806 0.26255832]
> y [0.63219791 0.35879577 0.96748029]
> xm [0.70422901 0.08023806 0.26255832]
> ym [0.70422901 0.84161698 0.26255832]
> ym - xm [0.         0.76137892 0.        ]
> norm(y - x) 0.7613789207408871
>
> x [0.73489304 0.54577026 0.95083131]
> y [0.82219623 0.42600696 0.34361226]
> xm [0.73489304 0.54577026 0.95083131]
> ym [0.73489304 1.17081432 0.95083131]
> ym - xm [0.         0.62504406 0.        ]
> norm(y - x) 0.6250440595015537
> ```

Comment: как определяется точка вокруг которой идет поворот?

Comment: @Grundy, я писал только про поворот. В этом смысле никак, повороты делаются вокруг глобального нуля. Если нужно следить и за трансляцией, то надо действовать так же как MBo: перенос в глобальный ноль, поворот, перенос обратно - переносы определяют точку поворота.

Comment: векторы приводятся к единичной длине до вычислений или в ходе вычислений?

Comment: @artem_tmm, все вектора во время вычислений должны быть единичной длины.

Comment: @artem_tmm, если вы добавите в вопрос нотацию для векторов и матриц (в виде примера) и язык программирования, можно будет записать всё в виде псевдокода.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy было бы очень хорошо если бы был представлен псевдокод,попробовал выполнить реализацию вашего алгоритма на python, код привел в вопросе. Результат не сходится с ожидаемым, возможно где то допустил ошибку, не могу понять где

Comment: @artem_tmm, добавил демо. В вашем коде я ошибок не нашёл. Мой код - рефакторинг вашего, добавлена отладочная печать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 1):

Применяем матрицу переноса на `(-A1.x, -A1.y, -A1.z)`
Теперь A1 в начале координат

Применяем матрицу поворота вокруг оси OZ на угол `f=atan2(A1.y-A2.y,A1.x-A2.x)`
Теперь вектор в плоскости OXZ

Применяем матрицу поворота вокруг оси OY на угол `t=acos((A1.z-A2.z)/Len(A))`
Теперь вектор коллинеарен OZ

Если нужно, перенос обратно `(A1.x, A1.y, A1.z)`

(знаки углов проверяйте, мог ошибиться)

Comment: как определяется точка вокруг которой идет поворот?

Comment: Вокруг конца A1. У автора это произвольная точка на отрезке, так что взять конец - ничему не противоречит. Точно также можно взять серединку.